# was finally SmartTarget included in Web 8?

Tags: smarttarget, web8

I have just installed Web8 and I can't see the section targeting nither I can find anything about promotions, smarttarget configs, DLLs, etc on Documentation Center (live content) nither inside of installation folder of SDL Web8.

Could anyone confirm this? 
I understood that it would be included in this new version...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SmartTarget, renamed as Experience optimization, was released with Cumulative Update 1 for SDL Web 8, but is not included like as Experience Manager, It still being an *Add-On*.

[Web 8 Add-On Products](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-625F137C-3FB5-4FEC-AF70-F94E6F4CF06A&addHistory=true&query=add%255C-ons&scope=&tid=a0b644d8-7674-4692-b2d2-f035e5269128&filename=GUID-625F137C-3FB5-4FEC-AF70-F94E6F4CF06A.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-625F137C-3FB5-4FEC-AF70-F94E6F4CF06A&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Web-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dadd%255C-ons&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1460467930105&currentQuery=add%255C-ons&currentScope=)

Answer (score 3):

Experience Optimization is scheduled for release on March 31st, as announced [here](https://community.sdl.com/products-solutions/solutions/customer_experience_cloud/digital-experience/tridion/b/weblog/archive/2016/03/01/sdl-web-q1-2016-update).

Comment: Thanks Nuno! do you know if this implementation will still use Fredhopper as engine of SmartTarget?

Comment: Yes, it still uses Fredhopper as the decision engine, and available on cloud and premise, just as before. There are safeguards in place to ensure we can apply our normal support policy (4 years + 1 optional) to this release.

Comment: I Just installed SDL Web 8.1.1 It seems finally is not included in this release. Neither Publication Mappings extension was included. Have you more information about this?Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Experience Optimization was released at the same time as 8.1.2